# Access of class to struct

Tags: c++

In order to do apply operations on point `M(x,y)`, I've defined a class `POINT2D.h`:

```
#ifndef POINT2D_H_INCLUDED

#define POINT2D_H_INCLUDED

class POINT2D {
    POINT2D ();                    //first constructor 
    POINT2D(double x,double y);    // second constructor

private:
    Point M, PointImage;

public:
    void DeclarerM(){
        std::cout << "Entrer les composantes du point M : " << " ";
        std::cin >> M.x >> M.y;
    }

    Point Trnaslation(Point M);         //Functions applied on Point
    Point Rotation(Point M);
    Point SymetrieAxiale (Point M);
    Point Homothetie(Point M);
};

#endif // POINT2D_H_INCLUDED
```

and a struct `Point` in the main:

```
struct Point{             //structure Point
    double x;                 //the coordinates of the Point
    double y;
};
```

When I run it I get an error in the class, saying "Point does not name a type". What is the problem?

Comment: Typically a header is included at the beginning of main .cpp. Thus, your POINT2D class has no knowledge of `struct point` even though it makes heavy use of it. See for forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ before you can use an type it must be declared or defined.  So since `POINT2D` does not know about the `Point` struct you declared in your main.cpp you cannot use it.  You can [forward declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration) `Point` or you move `Point` into its own header file and then include it in `POINT2D.h` and `main`.

You also have an issue with `POINT2D` as your constructors are both private.  You should add `public:` before them or move them into the `public` section that is already in your class.